# Bot Framework API, reply to messages

Tags: botframework, azure-api-apps

I have registered Bot channels on Azure portal and enabled Skype support. I'm trying to create a reply to skype messages as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-send-and-receive-messages?view=azure-bot-service-4.0).

I get user's message like: { ... 'type': 'message', 'id': '1579000...' ... }

And then use that id when sending POST to .../v3/conversations/{conversationId}/activities/1579000...

In a request body I also have 'replyToId': '1579000...'

The message, which is sent to skype, comes up without any quote inside (as usual message). What am I doing wrong? Do I understand how it should actually work (maybe this is not quoting, but something else)?

Comment: Just a quick check on something I noticed. Are you also replacing the conversationId? Can you also post your code to review/test with?

Comment: @StevenKanberg unfortunately, I can not post the code, but you can be sure that I use the same conversationId.